# Cisco AnyConnect VPN peculiar routing

Tags: vpn, routing, cisco-anyconnect

I have noticed that when my VPN connection (Cisco AnyConnect 3) is active, I have the following routing entry:

Persistent Routes:

Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric

```
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.254.144.1       1
```

In addition to:

Active Routes:

Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric

```
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.103     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.254.144.1    10.254.156.41      2
     10.254.144.0    255.255.240.0         On-link     10.254.156.41    257
    10.254.156.41  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.254.156.41    257
   10.254.159.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.254.156.41    257
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  134.191.232.120  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.103     26
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.103    281
      192.168.1.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.103     26
    192.168.1.103  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.103    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.103    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.103    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     10.254.156.41    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.103    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.254.156.41    257
```

Doesn't this mean that all other entries are pretty much irrelevant? So I wonder, why Cisco VPN cares to add all these routes...

Answer (score 0):

Usually the routing entries with the longest subnet mask (i.e. 255.255.255.255) are matched first, until entries with 0.0.0.0 are matched. That is why entries with 0.0.0.0 are often called "Route of last ressort".

So all the entries added by Cisco VPN will be used.